# Configuring MySQL on EC2 to be accessible both locally and remotely

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

EC2 instances have an Amazon "internal" IP address (something like 10.228.105.159) and one that can be used from the outside world (e.g. 46.137.103.122).

I used to access a MySQL database only from within the instance itself, but now need to change that. In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I've commented out `skip-external-locking`, and I replaced

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

... with the EC2 *internal* IP address, which got remote access working ok (with appropriate EC2 security group settings, of course). But now it can't be accessed by processes locally using a database url such as `mysql://localhost/dbname`.

Is it possible to both have remote access working *and* still use "localhost" when connecting to the database locally? If so, how? (Or do I just have to change local configurations to also use an IP like 10.228.105.159 when connecting to the MySQL db on the same host?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just comment this line or provide 0.0.0.0, and it will bind to all addresses.